# Function that checks if in root of binary tree is stored number bigger then in all child nodes

Tags: c, binary-tree

It will be helpful if this function is bool. When i try this, function returns only false.

```
bool compare(tree *root,tree *root2){ 

if(root==NULL) return false;

    return((root->number <= root2->number) && compare(root->left, root2) 
                                           && compare(root->right, root2));
}
```

So, root2 doesn't change value, it exist only to compare the root number with all others.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Does it crash?  Does it give you wrong answers some of the time?  Does it give you wrong answers all of the time?  Have you stepped through it in a debugger to see which part is crashing or giving you wrong answers?

Comment: It gives wrong result. I will edit in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a reasonable looking tree, the following code segment will at some point always return false. Since you're and-ing that with your top level compare, that will be false too.

```
&& compare(root->left, root2) && compare(root->right, root2)
```

The reason why this part of the branch will always eventually be false is the first statement:

```
if(root==NULL) return false;
```

I think you want that to be looking at root2, not root

So, change it to this:

```
if(root2==NULL) return false;
```

Then beneath that you can compare against root, but it's the opposite.

```
if(root==NULL) return true;
```

You want to return false if root2 is null (null isn't bigger than anything), but true if root is null (everything is bigger than null).

Answer (score 1):

Change `false` to `true` in base case.

```
if(root==NULL) return true;
```

This is because, if any node is NULL, it's parent satisfies the property that the parent's value is larger than the child's value (since no child in this case). So return true.

Also, pre-check that `root2` is not NULL.